# Powershell Get-ChildItem cmlet with '-recurse' optional

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to use the parameter `-Recurse` into `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet depending on a value of another variable.

I mean, let's say that we have the boolean parameter `$flag`, if `$flag` is `True` I would like to insert the parameter `-Recurse` into `Get-ChildItem` execution, otwerwise not.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Switch parameters do allow for a boolean to be passed in if used with a colon '`:`'

Example:

```
$flag = $true
Get-ChildItem -Recurse:$flag
```

Will use `-Recurse`

```
$flag = $false
Get-ChildItem -Recurse:$flag
```

Will **NOT** use `-Recurse`

Comment: I don't see this technique being used very much, seems to be something from "the old days".

Comment: Hadn't really noticed tbh. "From the old days" seems to imply that there's a new way...share the knowledge @Snak3d0c , I want to know! :D

Comment: That's not what i meant hehe. I'm just saying that this technique isn't been used that often anymore (or so it seems). I used to come across it a bit more.

Comment: I use it quite often with -Confirm